# Upload a File from the Google Chrome File System to a Server

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, filesystems

Chrome has a very useful File System API that I am using. What I am trying to do is upload a file stored within it to a server. Unfortunately, it seems like the only way that one can send a file to a server is by submitting a form wherein the user explicitly chooses the file to upload because of some security issues.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Peter

---

So I have this idea. Why not convert the blob to a string using a FileReader and then send it in the body of a request?

```
//entries[] contains a set of file objects
function readerSuccess(entries) {
   var i;
   for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) 
   {
       if(entries[i].isFile === true)
       {
        data=new FormData();
    data.append('name',entries[i].fullPath);

    //Conversion...
    entries[i].file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            var dataStr=this.result;

            };

        reader.readAsText(file);
     }, errorHandler);

   //Sending...
 data.append('file',dataStr);
 var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 oReq.open("POST", "serv.php", true);
 oReq.send(data);


    }
    else if (entries[i].isDirectory === true)
    {
    getDirSuccess(entries[i]);
    }
  }
 }
```

The problem is that now it's sending blobs as separate messages.
For example:
Request URL:blob:http%3A//localhost/7492a164-ed62-4834-939c-e6437b52cba8
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)

Comment: What is your question?  If you are asking if you can programmatically choose a file from the user's (client's) file system and upload it without any user intervention, the answer is "no".

Comment: I got that... but the thing is, I'm using the Chrome's File System (Google File System API). I have file objects that are basically blobs. And I can't send them

Comment: Just `append` each `Blob` to your `FormData` object, and then send the `FormData` object via XHR2.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Would you mind giving me a small example? I am very new to this.

Comment: I found this awesome tutorial online. The site is really good.   http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you are using FileReader here.  Just append each Blob/File to your FormData object and send it:

```
var data = new FormData();
if(entries[i].isFile)
{
   data.append('file' + i , entries[i]);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "serv.php", true);
oReq.send(data);
```

Comment: I've tried it but... I have different files of different sizes in my system and I'm trying to store them in a MySQL database via PHP. They're all occupying 18B of space. Odd that. Am I right in accessing each file as $_POST['file'+i]   ?

Comment: I'm not fluent in PHP, but I believe you should grab the files server-side using the $_FILES global.

Comment: Thanks Mr Nicholus. Unfortunately, the $_FILES global is empty. It has something to do with needing an <input> tag. Which I do not want to use...